# What Data points can I get from an Authenticated YouTube Channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I'm having some issues finding the API data that can be gathered from YouTube channels that have authenticated with my application.

Certain data points, specifically audience data, can only be gathered once a YouTube Channel has authenticated.  Where can I find these data points?

Thanks!

Comment: "Can you elaborate your question? Also, try to check this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first if it helps."

Comment: @KENdi Sorry if my request isn't clear.  

I am unable to find the documents that explain what advanced API requests can be made on a user once that user has authenticated their YouTube channel with my app.

Certain data, like audience info, is only attainable through users being authenticated.  I would imagine there is a page that outlines each API call, but after hours of searching I cannot find it.